# Трейты. Добавить метод в класс если выполнено условие

Tags: php, интерфейс, traits

Прошу помочь с заданием из учебника:

> Создайте трейт Auth, который при наличии переменных класса $email и
>   $password добавлял бы в класс метод auth(), принимающий в качестве
>   аргумента электронный адрес и пароль. В случае успешного сопоставления
>   метод должен помещать в сессию информацию о том, что пользователь
>   аутентифицирован. Другой метод is_auth() при этом должен возвращать
>   true или false в зависимости от того, пройдена аутентификация или нет.
>   Если переменных $email и $password в классе нет, методы не должны
>   появляться, даже если трейт Auth подмешан в класс.

1. Что имеется в виду под сопоставлением? Должно производиться сравнение передаваемых значений $email и $password с чем-то?
2. Трейт Auth должен и проверять существование переменных `( if (isset($this->email) && isset($this->password)) )` в классе и добавлять в класс метод auth (как это сделать? Через интерфейсы?) ?

```
trait Auth

{
    public function check() {
        if (isset($this->email) && isset($this->password)) {
            //Требуется добавить метод auth($email, $password) в класс
            //Можно ли как-то через $this выполнить class A implements InterAuth
            //где вместо class A будет $this?
        }
    }
}



interface InterAuth
{
    public function auth($this->email, $this->password);
}


class A implements InterAuth {
    public $email = "random@random.com";
    public $password = "12345";
}
```

Comment: Очень странное задание... Если посмотреть документацию Trait, там нет условий добавлений методов. Можно что-нить накостылить через __call но это вряд ли, то что нужно.

Comment: @Pavel скорее через рефлексию. Что является каким-то костылём)

Comment: @Temik2704 на самом деле мы тут можем долго гадать, что имели в виду авторы. Потому что ничего подобного без костылей жутких в голову не приходит. Как я понимаю ответов на задания нет?)

Comment: @СергейМишин рефлексия вроде только достает данные о классе, не добавляет методы и т.д.

Comment: @Pavel значит через https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.runkit-method-add.php Помню что была такая возможность в пыхе, уже запамятовал где конкретно. Но через __call тоже можно)

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/macroable/blob/master/src/Macroable.php - вот пример "динамического добавления метода" в класс. Если это поможет. Но имхо это уже за пределами знаний о трейтах и их возможностей

Comment: ответа на задание в учебнике нет

Comment: @Temik2704 тогда нет смысла выполнять задания. Ведь они служат не только для того, чтобы закрепить материал, но и для того, чтобы понять, точно ли ты понял всё так, как понял. Сравнить и понять ошибки и доисправить их. А так, можно хоть верблюда создать, которого дрессируют сто людей и через месяц тот может копытом набрать телефон индуса, который понимает на верблюжьем и согласится написать код, который через блокнот по cron'у добавляет или удаляет строчку кода :DDDD  Задача выполнена? Да. А правильно ли. Как узнать